# How to turn on GZIP compression on ruby THIN server (Rails 3.1) on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gzip, thin

I wonder how to enable GZIP compression on my Ruby THIN server on windows machine for Rails 3.1 app?

Well, i've never worked with GZIP before.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let Apache or Nginx do the compression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial will help you set up Nginx and Thin:http://www.funonrails.com/2010/03/nginx-and-thin-installation-and.html

And from what I understand, you can turn on gzip through Nginx configuration file.  This shows the Nginx HttpGzipModule:  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to setup it on my windows devoloper's machine, where I've got Ruby Thin Server but no Nginix.

Comment: In that case, you may want to look at this tutorial for setting up Nginx and Thin on a Windows platform - just in case you have any issues:  http://www.beechtreetech.com/ruby-on-rails-thin-and-nginx-on-windows.  I currently have Thin running on a Windows 7 environment with a Rails 3.0.10 app, but haven't tried 3.1 yet.